# Existence of surjection vs injection over $\sf ZF$

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

Consider the following statements in $\sf ZF$:

> (S) If $A, B$ are nonempty sets, then there is a surjection $s:A \to B$, or there is a surjection $t:B\to A$.

> (I) If $A, B$ are sets, then there is an injection $i:A\to B$, or there is an injection $j:B\to A$.

Note that (I) implies (S). Assuming $\sf AC$, both statements are true.

**Question.** Is there a model of $\sf ZF$ in which (S) holds, but not (I)?

Comment: Both imply AC...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The answer is no. Both (I) and (S) are equivalent to AC over ZF. Indeed, for any set $S$ the class of ordinals $\alpha$ such that $\alpha$ injects into $S$ (resp. $S$ surjects onto $\alpha$) is a set, so there is some ordinal $\beta$ outside this set. Assuming (I) (resp. (S)), there is an injection $S\to\beta$ (resp. surjection $\beta\to S$). In the latter case, we also get an injection $S\to\beta$, by taking any element $S$ to the least element in its preimage. In either case, we see $S$ is well-orderable. Thus both (I) and (S) imply well-ordering theorem and hence AC.

Since both (I) and (S) are equivalent to AC, they are also equivalent to each other.

Comment: *for any set $S$ the class of ordinals $\alpha$ such that $\alpha$ injects into $S$ (resp. $S$ surjects onto $\alpha$) is a set.*

Is there a simple argument to see this (especially for the "surjects" part)?

Comment: @MartinVäth For injections: for any $S$, you can form the set $A$ of all isomorphism classes of well-orders on subsets of $S$. By replacement, mapping each element of $A$ to its order type gives the class of ordinals which inject into $S$. For surjections, note that if $S$ surjects onto $\alpha$, then $\alpha$ injects into $P(S)$.

Comment: Thank you. So the argument is essentially the same than proving/using Hartog's theorem (for injections) or the analogous [Lindenbaum theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2141961/826997) (for surjections). These are not hard, but I was hoping for an essentially simpler proof.

Comment: @MartinVäth Hartogs' and Lindenbaum's theorems are precisely what my argument uses. I have essentially just expanded the arguments for their proofs.